# How to find minimum?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Is it possible to  find exactly (not numerically) the minimum of the function $$\sqrt{15-12\cos(x)}+\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}\sin(x)}+\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{3}\sin(x)}+\sqrt{10-4\sqrt{3}\sin(x)-6\cos(x)} $$ on the interval $[0,2\pi)$ ? Maple 18 and  Mathematica 10 fail with it.

Comment: The derivative of the function cancels at $x=\pi/3$ and the minimum is exactly $6$. The big question is how to prove it.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Thank you for your interest to the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%2815-12*cos%28x%29%29%2Bsqrt%284-2*sqrt%283%29*sin%28x%29%29%2Bsqrt%287-4*sqrt%283%29*sin%28x%29%29%2Bsqrt%2810-4*sqrt%283%29*sin%28x%29-6*cos%28x%29%29

seems that minimum is 6
[image]

Comment: How is this a *nonnumerical* answer?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen , I think it can help someone in getting nonnumerical answer

Comment: Numerically, the minimum is attained at approximately $1.5599$ (which is suspiciously close to, but clearly diffrent from $\frac\pi 2$) with a value of about $6.6248$.

Comment: Oh, dammit. Forget my comments - my PARI/GP converted to power series too early.

Comment: Anwer is 6 ($x=pi/3$)